# Target nth-child of the child element on mouseover the parent div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have overlay `div` and on its mouseover the child `div` is displayed. what I want is to adjust the left position percentage based on the`nth-child` selector. Such as if its the first div then the left should be 50% and second element's left should be 40% and so on. How can I do it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row mycustombox">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
            <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
            <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; display: none; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
                <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
            <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
            <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; display: none; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
                <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
            <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
            <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; display: none; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
                <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
            <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
            <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; display: none; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
                <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.customoverlay {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.customoverlay img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.customoverlay .inneroverlaybox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    background: #002137;
}
.customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.customoverlay:hover .inneroverlaybox { opacity: 1; }
.customoverlay:hover .inneroverlaybox h3:nth-child(1) { left: 1.5%; }
.customoverlay:hover .inneroverlaybox h3:nth-child(2) { left: 40% !important; }
.customoverlay:hover .inneroverlaybox h3:nth-child(3) { left: 40% !important; }
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/tvubL06s/)?

Comment: Please be more clear in your desired structure. Like @Harry, I didnt get the point either

Comment: @Harry yes i am looking for something like this. Please post it as an answer so i can select it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it looks you are trying to set the `left` position based on whether the `h3` is present inside the first container or the second or third (and not the `h3` element's child index). So, the `nth-child` pseudo-class selector should be applied to the container.

So, your selector needs to be something like the below:

```
div > div:nth-child([n]):hover .customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3
```

Applying the `:nth-child` selector to `h3` or `div.inneroverlaybox` or `a.customoverlay` will not give the expected output because they are all the first (and only child) of their parent.

```css
.customoverlay {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.customoverlay img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.customoverlay .inneroverlaybox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  background: #002137;
}
.customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
div > div:hover .inneroverlaybox {
  opacity: 1;
}
div > div:nth-child(1):hover .customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3 {
  left: 1.5%;
}
div > div:nth-child(2):hover .customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3 {
  left: 40% !important;
}
div> div:nth-child(3):hover .customoverlay .inneroverlaybox h3 {
  left: 40% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row mycustombox">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
      <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
      <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
        <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
      <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
      <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
        <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
      <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
      <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
        <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="height: 300px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <a href="#" class="customoverlay">
      <img src="http://silver11.net/door/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Furniture-EDI-for-the-Furniture-Industry.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
      <div class="inneroverlaybox" style="height: 300px; transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;">
        <h3 data-fontsize="16" data-lineheight="24">World Class EDI for the Home Furnishing Industry</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I also removed the `display: none` inline style from `div.inneroverlaybox` because otherwise the element will not get displayed (as inline styles take precedence) and even if we add `!important` in CSS style, the transition won't happen as `display` is not a transitionable property.